# Erro ao executar function em PL/SQL

Tags: java, oracle, pl-sql, procedure

**Código**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BuscaNome
  RETURN t_name
 IS 
  t_name VARCHAR(20); 
BEGIN 

  SELECT T.DS_TURMA INTO t_name
   FROM TURMA T WHERE T.CD_TURMA = 13;

 RETURN t_name;
END;
```

**Erro:**

> Erro: PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated Erro(2,10):
>   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
>   incomplete or malformed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No return da declaração da função vc tem que colocar o tipo, não a variável.
No teu caso, seria:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BuscaNome RETURN VARCHAR IS
```

Isso porque o tipo da variável que vai retornar é VARCHAR.